# Laravel get or paginate subquery

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have a huge query that sometimes will require me to use paginate() and other times will require me to use `get()`. Is there a way to create some kind of if statement right at the end of the query that will determine which one to use? Kinda like a where subquery.

Other solutions I came up with was to set the paginate number to a really high number to mimic `get()`, but I'd much rather do it the other way if it's possible to use some kind of if statement but I wasn't really sure how to figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you CAN put conditionals.

e.g. Let's say your database code is like this:

```
$data = DB::table('test')->get(); // or paginate
```

then

```
$temp = DB::table('test');

if(condition)
{
    return $temp->paginate();
} else {
    return $temp->get();
}
```

if you want to check what type of data, it is returning (*in controller*)

```
if($data instanceof \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator)
{
    //it is a paginator object. write the code accordingly
} else {
    // It is returning array.
}
```

Though you should further validate to see what's coming through.

#### Another route:

you can call the `items()` method on the paginator object to get the results with reference to that particluar page.

e.g. if `$data` is a paginator object, then,

```
dd($data->items());
```

will print the items as an array. (`items()` returns the resultset as an array)